# Two Regular Expression Problems

Tags: regex

1- I'm planning to use the regEx to validate user first and last name inputs using this regex:

```
/^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]+$/u
```

However I don't want to allow underscore "_", no only empty space (cannot be left blank) and at least 2 characters. How can I appy them to the regEx above ?

2- For my strong password input validation, I need it be of minimum 8 character length
and it should consist of at least one letter and non-letter ( For e.g. qsgtest123, qsgtest!@#)

I will be grateful if you help me with these 2 regExs.

Comment: perl? boost? C++11? Javascript? Vim? What is your tool? *regex* alone does not mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

This for the name

```
/^(?! +$)[a-zA-ZàáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]{2,}$/u
```

The only difference is the "at least 2 characters" at the end and `(?! +$)` that means "fail if there are only spaces and end of the string".

Tester: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2uv74

And this one for the password:

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-ZàáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð])(?=.*[^a-zA-ZàáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð]).{8,}$/u
```

(I'm using your definition of "letter" :-) ). It means:

```
look forward if present any character any number of times followed by a "letter"
look forward if present any character any number of times followed by a "non-letter"
(these two look forward don't "move" the regex cursor, that is still at the first character)
match any character 8 or more times
```

I see you are using the `/u` at the end of the regex. You are probably using Perl. To match any letter you should use `\p{L}` (and to match any non-letter you should use `\P{L}`) instead of writing long lists of characters. So the first one would become:

```
/^(?! +$)[\p{L} ,.'-]{2,}$/u
```

and the password one:

```
/^(?=.*\p{L})(?=.*\P{L}).{8,}$/u
```

And we will ignore the composable diacritics of Unicode :-)

Unless you'd prefer to include them... Then

```
/^(?! +$)(?=.{2,})(\p{L}\p{M}*|[ ,.'-])*$/u
```

(we pre-check the absence of all-spaces and the minimum length, and then we check that all the string is composed of letters (each one with an optional zero or more combining mark) or the other symbols in the `[]`)

Comment: What if user enters only letter? Like aaaaaaaaaaaa. Won't your regex match?

Comment: @FailedDev The password one? No. The second look forward looks for at least a non-letter.

Comment: I see I see. Hard to see with the huge character class :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
/^[\p{L},.'-]+[\p{L} ,.'-]*[\p{L},.'-]+$/u
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/^((?!_)[a-zA-ZàáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-])+$/u
```

The above should apply to your first question.